# Problemas con XMLHttpRequest.send, ¿por que .send() no recibe parámetros?

Tags: javascript

Estoy simplemente probando ajax por javascript nativo creando un objeto xhr, colocándole sus atributos como xhr.open, xhr.onreadystatechange y cuando intento enviar por .send(param) se envía como si no hubiera parametros en param:

`var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'ajax.php');
var param = 'persona=123123';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.response);
   }
}
xhr.send(param);`<--- XHTR no recibe los parametros.

Mientras que usando:
`xhr.open('get','ajax.php?persona=123123');`

si funciona, pero no lo quiero de esa manera, lo que quiero saber es por qué no recibe los parámetros en .send(), ya que veo muchas guías de que se envía por .send().

Answer (score 1):

Los parametros en el metodo send solo se usan cuando haces la petición ajax via POST.

```
xhttp.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
xhttp.send(param);
```

Tan solo sustituye el primer parámetro del metodo "open" y haz la petición ajax vía post en lugar de get.

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'ajax.php');
var param = 'persona=123123';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.response);
   }
xhr.send(param);
```

Comment: Funciona pero hace falta hacer un new FormData() para el .send():
`var param = new FormData();

param.append('persona','123456');

** CODIGO **

xhr.send(param);`